# Is my jQuery CDN url correct?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

Could anyone confirm the the CDN `src` link for jQuery?

I am using the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Your `src` url looks fine. There are three main CDNs for jQuery, found here: http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have used the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() 
{

/--my code
)};
```

Its working for IE and Firefox

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the URL and your `script` tag are correct.  By the way, jQuery 1.4.3 was recently released.

Answer (score 1):

The question is very vague but it is related to SharePoint and CDN-hosted copy of jQuery, so I'll try to guess - **does a page using jQuery from Microsoft CDN work incorrectly in Internet Explorer?** If yes, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/879137/95) and consider using your own copy of jQuery (I had this problem and I found no solution).

Comment: I have used the following code: <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() 
{