# Jquery .get() not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm having a problem with, guess what, IE8. The following code, simplified for clarity, does not work at all:

```
alert('before get');

$.get(getActivityURL('ActionName',{
    ts: new Date().getTime(), ...other params...}), 
{cache:false;},
    function (xml) {
    alert("in get callback");
},'xml'); // End $.get()

alert('in after get');
```

The getActivityUrl() outputs a valid URL with request parameters.

This works correctly in FF and Chrome. However, in IE8, this doesn't even get into the $.get() callback. I get the "before" and "after" alerts, but not the "in" alert and indeed, nothing happens and the request is NOT sent. I don't really know what to think here.

The response headers are "Content-Type:application/xml; charset:iso-8859-1" as confirmed in FF.

EDIT: $.post() doesn't work, either.

Comment: Could you provide the complete function call, rather than one with bits missed out?  Your current code wouldn't work in any browser.

Comment: This exact code works in every browser save IE8. The "getActivityUrl(...)" returns a valid URL.

Answer (score 12):

IE is infamous for caching. So you need to make sure you are not getting a cached result.

You can disable caching globally by setting the cache property value to false in the [`ajaxStart`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) method.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});
```

Or If you want to eliminate the cached result in a specific ajax call, Append a unique number to the end of the url. You may use the [`$.now()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.now/) method to get a unique number

```
$.get("someurl.php?" + $.now() ,function(result) {
   // do something with result
});
```

`$.now()` method return a number representing the current time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is a problem but try to remove ";"  in {cache:false}

IE doesn't like any additional stuff in {},  eg 
{a:a,b:b,c:c,} will work in FF but not in IE

Answer (score 1):

I think so there is Cache problem in IE.

So add `Math.random()`, one more parameter at the end like `"&mathRandom="+Math.random();`
Because IE will recognise same request as previous one so it will give data from cache instead of firing request.

Answer (score 0):

```
$J.get(getActivityURL('ActionName'

// End $.get()
```

Is this correct? I mean $J... Are you using more than one JS framework or something?

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention that, it is correctly "no-conflicted" throughout the application. Anyways, I just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

have u tried:

```
$.ajax({
  url: getActivityURL('ActionName',{ts: new Date().getTime(), ...other params...}),
  data: data,
  success: function (xml) {
               alert("in get callback");
            },
  dataType: 'xml'
});
```

Just a guess

EDIT:

I found a interesting thread that might help you, check this out:

[jQuery issue in Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879137/problem-with-jquery-in-internet-explorer-8)

Comment: Same as before, no change (I also included type:'GET'). Still it works in every other browser, but not in effing IE

Comment: Try this .ajax variation, but also add an "error" parameter and check for an error message there.