# Addclass not working in IE8 jquery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

Addclass isn't workign in IE in the following code:

```
$("tr").find("td:eq(0)").addClass("header").css("width","300px");
$("tr").find("td:eq(1)").addClass("data").css("width","500px;");
```

Comment: **More detail needed.** How about showing some markup? What do you mean by _"isn't working?"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was bad markup on my part. Didn't close "TD" tags and didn't remove a legacy "CENTER" tag on the page. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

$trFind = $("tr").find("td:eq(0)");
$trFind.addClass("header").css("width","300px");

That's how it should work.

Comment: Why would this help at all? Chaining is an integral part of jQuery, and this is a case where it makes _total_ sense to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will still have the issue and looking for a solution:

[jQuery Add and remove Classes not working IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893361/jquery-add-and-remove-classes-not-working-ie8/19972627#19972627)

Answer (score -1):

see that:

[jQuery issue in Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879137/problem-with-jquery-in-internet-explorer-8)