# IE8 Jquery 1.8.3 issue: Syntax error line 2 chart 13575

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

I'm having a problem with `Jquery 1.8.3` and `IE8` the problem I have is that at the moment I open the web page with `IE8` I've got the next error and I can't submit the form:

> Syntax error Jquery 1.8.3.js Sintax Error line: 2 char: 13575

I think my  problem is with my javascript but I do not know what I'm missing:

The [JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/Verurteilt/6009292) the [Web Page](http://carlyleonline.scalahed.com/)

Thank's in advance! :D

**EDIT**

The web page works in `IE >= 10`

Comment: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/empty-div-issue-in-ie8

Comment: Why do all education sites use that stock photography girl? lol

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879137/problem-with-jquery-in-internet-explorer-8

Comment: @epascarello I do not know.

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres:is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem arises since your function_form output is different for IE8 and other browsers. In IE you get response like this one (error 500 which is html):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator,
 root@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred,
and anything you might have done that may have
caused the error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at carlyleonline.scalahed.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

and then it fails with:
`var datas = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);`

Other browsers on the other hand return proper JSON:

```
{"errores": {"entidad": ["Este campo es obligatorio."], "fecha_nacimiento": ["Este campo es obligatorio."], "apellido_paterno": ["Este campo es obligatorio."], "carlyle_lic1": ["Seleccione al menos una licenciatura."], "celular": ["Proporcione un n\u00famero telef\u00f3nico."], "nombre": ["Este campo es obligatorio."], "email": ["Este campo es obligatorio."]}}
```

Can you show us your logic which determines if response should be json or webserver error?