# Loading jquery in IE8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I get the error:

```
jquery is undefined.
```

I have this in my head:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I've checked this thread and tried a number of solution suggested but none work.

[jQuery issue in Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879137/problem-with-jquery-in-internet-explorer-8)

Comment: jquery dropped support for IE 6, 7 and 8 from 2.0.0 onwards.. http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/

Comment: no more support for IE8 in 2.x jquery branch

Comment: What should I use then?

Comment: @panthro lastest 1.x jquery version... 1.x will still support older browsers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the 2.x versions of jQuery do not support older versions of IE, try using an older version of jQuery...

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, will accept when it lets me.