# Expected identifier string or number on Internet Explorer 8 and jQuery 1.9.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm getting one issue on Internet Explorer 8 and jQuery 1.9.1. Here is some information:

First is the picture about my issue:

[image: Expected identifier string or number]

Below is settings for IE:

[image: Compatibility view settings]

The jQuery version **1.9.1**

The IE version **8.0.7601.17514**

The address of website is: **10.20.234.11:8643**

This is meta tags in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge; chrome=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
```

(I didn't config on the server. This **X-UA-Compatible** I configed in HTML.

Thanks so much. Please question me if you have any questions.

Comment: Please show the jQuery statements you have. They are the ones that give errors. Also you might want to search some more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879137/jquery-issue-in-internet-explorer-8

Comment: My jQuery is minified. Please wait I will show you in 15 mins.

Comment: see https://jquery.com/browser-support/ ... from memory jquery 1.7 something is suitable for IE8 or lower emulation modes.... nobody uses IE8 any more and it is unsupported... Enterprise intranets can use Enterprise Site Mode lists to force IE11 to use lower emulation modes to support legacy non-standards, but you should code new intranet sites to modern standards and allow IE to use the default emulation mode. Adding a site to the Compatibility View list (when not using enterprise site mode lists) forces IE to use IE7 emulation.

Comment: Develop for your intranet sites using IE11 and check the Emulation tab of the dev tool for the current Emulation mode (aka documentMode) that it assumes and how it was determined (Enterprise site mode lists, meta x-ua, header x-ua, user CVL). When debugging in IE11 make sure that you choose the "Always break on exceptions" from the dropdown on the Debug tab, and do not close the dev tool while testing your pages. By default IE will use "Never break on exceptions". IE10 and higher emulation modes ignore conditional comments.

Comment: Hi all. Thanks so much. It seems jQuery has dropped for IE 8 since version 2.0. I've tried to use version 1.9. It's working.